How to compute inertia tensor off the center of mass with geometric algebra?
I was reading Doran & Lasenby's Geometric Algebra for Physicists when I stumbled upon this,

where $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector taken form the centre of mass. Returning to the definition of equation (3.121) we see that we need to compute
$$\mathcal{I}_a\left(B\right)=\int\,\mathrm{d}^3x\, \rho\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\right)\wedge\left(\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\right)\cdot B\right).\tag{3.123}$$
The integral evaluates to give
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_a\left(B\right)&=\int\,\mathrm{d}^3x\, \rho\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\left(\mathbf{x}\cdot B\right)-\mathbf{x}\wedge\left(\mathbf{a}\cdot B\right)-\mathbf{a}\wedge\left(\mathbf{x}\cdot B\right)+\mathbf{a}\wedge\left(\mathbf{a}\cdot B\right)\right)\\
&=\mathcal{I}(B)+M\mathbf{a}\wedge\left(\mathbf{a}\cdot B\right).\tag{3.124}\end{align}

Seems like bringing the integral in or out the wedge product is wrong. Or maybe it's the vector bivector dot product.
I tried taking the integral into each term, the second term in result had a minus sign. I tried grouping the second and the fourth term of second line to make $\rho (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})$ which integrates to zero, but that leaves me with the third term which I took the integral in, the result also had a minus sign.
How to properly do this math to go from the second line to the result?

Let us do the simplest stuff first. You know what the first term simplifies into. The last term goes by $\vec a\wedge(\vec a\cdot B)\int\mathrm d^3x\,\rho=M\vec a\wedge(\vec a\cdot B)$ by Equation (3.118)
It is important to remember that both $\vec a\cdot B$ and $\vec x\cdot B$ are vectors. So, by applying Equation (2.4) and Equation (2.61), we can obtain that
$$
\begin{align}
       \vec x\wedge(\vec a\cdot B)+\vec a\wedge(\vec x\cdot B)
\tag1&=\frac12[\vec x(\vec   a\cdot B)-(\vec   a\cdot B)\vec x
              +\vec a(\vec   x\cdot B)-(\vec   x\cdot B)\vec a]\\
\tag2&=\frac14[\vec x(\vec aB-B\vec a)-(\vec aB-B\vec a)\vec x
              +\vec a(\vec xB-B\vec x)-(\vec xB-B\vec x)\vec a]
\end  {align}
$$
This might look like a tremendous mess, but it is made of constants $\vec a$ and $B$ and the linear dependence on $\vec x$, so again, Equation (3.118) applies, zeroing them all.
Of course, after a while, we get used to these manipulations and can immediately see that these will be zeroed.
